# Dynamically load .NET assembly in C++ application so that it's version independant

Tags: c++, .net, clr

I am writing a C++ application and I would like to use .NET's Rijndael class that exists in .NET since version 1.1.

To be able to use it within my application, I have to enable /clr but that will also bind my app to certain framework (the one I had during compilation).

My question is if I can somehow dynamically load proper assembly (in this case mscorlib.dll) whichever version exists on the machine this program runs on. I know that this can lead to crash if an assembly i.e. does not have method that I will be trying to call but assume that I am very careful and that I know that methods names/types did not change over .NET versions.

So basically what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to run this app on a system despite which .net framework is installed there.

Comment: It's not just .net version that could be different, it's CLR version too. Because of that you will need to do *CLR hosting*, and select the correct runtime to host depending on what's installed. Lot's of work, but doable.

Comment: So I guess the way to go is to use c++'s AES library in this particular case. e: the reason I didn't want to do that is that I had c# code that I could just copy paste (almost) into c++ app but I dont want to make it .net version dependent.

Comment: Yep, that what I'd do.